# Correct the "about" page to reference the new "on hold" policy

Tags: feature-request, tour, on-hold

This is a bit of a nitpick, but on the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page on StackOverflow, it states that:

> Questions that need improvement may be closed until someone fixes them.

This should probably be tweaked given the new ["on hold"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1) policy. The original also seems a tad passive to me -- perhaps it would be more helpful if it were reworded in a way to encourage new users to be proactive in editing their own questions to get them reopened?

Answer (score 2):

“On hold” is essentially a synonym for “closed”. The about page paints broad strokes. It should not be burdened by fine distinctions that aren't even meaningful.